# Difference between hot reloading vs calling setState?

Tags: flutter

I think hot reloading is equivalent to calling `setState` but the following code contradicts this.

My `State` subclass:

```dart
class _FooPageState extends State<FooPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      // Calling setState every 1 second.
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => CustomPaint(painter: FooPainter());
}
```

My custom painter:

```dart
class FooPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) => print('paint');

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

As you can see after 1s I'm calling `setState`, however, the print statement in `paint` method isn't invoked every second. But as soon as I do hot reload using IDE shortcut, it does print the statement.

**Note:** I know I can return `true` from `shouldRepaint` to make the print statement work but that's not the question.

Comment: This is just a theory I might be wrong. The initState runs at the beginning of the build method and it runs once. Though you have given the Timer.periodic. it just runs at one time. Try using the didUpdateWidget.

Comment: @imgkl Unfortunately you're wrong. Had it been a regular `Timer` it would have run just once but this is `Timer.periodic` which runs after every duration you've specified.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I didn't know that.